# how can i add animate function here

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to show some div contents when user click a show more button and then hide the div contents when user click a hide button, i want to make this function with some animation. here is my script :

```
$(document).ready(function(){  //Toggling between more results
    $('.loadMoreDiv').click(function(){  
        $('#loadMoreDiv').hide();  
        $('#hideMoreDiv').show();  
        $('.old_message_block').removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');  
        $('#messagesLabel').text('showing all messages');  
    });  
    $('.lessMoreDiv').click(function(){  
        $('#hideMoreDiv').hide();  
        $('#loadMoreDiv').show();  
        $('.old_message_block').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');  
        $('#messagesLabel').text('Most Recent message');  
    });  
});
```

and my jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/JkuW3/1/)

Comment: ...with "some" animation? What kind, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   //Toggling between more results

   $('.loadMoreDiv').click(function(){
     $('#loadMoreDiv').hide();
     $('#hideMoreDiv').show();       
     $('.old_message_block').slideDown(500).removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');
     $('#messagesLabel').text('showing all messages');
   });

   $('.lessMoreDiv').click(function(){
     $('#hideMoreDiv').hide(); 
     $('#loadMoreDiv').show(); 
     $('.old_message_block').slideUp(500).removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');    
     $('#messagesLabel').text('Most Recent message');
   });    

 });
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick fix: http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/JkuW3/1/

But I'd write that thing completely different anyway:

http://jsfiddle.net/UPWpB/1/

Comment: There you go. Edited my answer with the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQUery [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) and [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  //Toggling between more results
    $('.loadMoreDiv').click(function(){  
        $('#loadMoreDiv').hide();  
        $('#hideMoreDiv').show();  
        $('.old_message_block').fadeIn();  
        $('#messagesLabel').text('showing all messages');  
    });  
    $('.lessMoreDiv').click(function(){  
        $('#hideMoreDiv').hide();  
        $('#loadMoreDiv').show();  
        $('.old_message_block').fadeOut();  
        $('#messagesLabel').text('Most Recent message');  
    });  
});
```

**Edit**: Applied the functions to the correct elements.

Comment: please check my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/JkuW3/6/ then you will understand my question, see i want slide toggle effect for the div content which are showing after user clicks the show more button

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#book').toggle('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

show this link http://api.jquery.com/toggle/